# Quaternions and Rotations

Tags: quaternions

I have 2 points in 3d space ,point A= <5,3,6> and B=<8,2,3>

I want to rotate "point B" by 30 degree from point A.

how do I solve this question using quaternion.

Plz, explain the steps....

Comment: Is this a question about the computing software *Mathematica*? If so, can you give more details about how what you mean? If not, perhaps this belongs on another site.

Comment: I am new to this subject and I cannot find good worked out examples for beginners

Comment: Okay, but what does this question have to do with the computing software *Mathematica*? And how do quaternions relate to rotations? And what does it mean to "rotate a point" (perhaps you really mean the vector)? Anyway, we are not a tutoring service. If you don't know much about the topic itself, then this isn't really a *Mathematica* question; it's more of a [math.se] question. Please include more information in your post, and explain how it's related to *Mathematica*.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.